# Implementing phone number for Google Places using Swift

Tags: api, swift, maps, google-places-api

I am trying to implement a simple app which displays Taxi companies on a map. These can then be clicked and information about each company is displayed, however; I am unable to display the phone number for each company. This phone number would need to be tappable and then the phone call is initiated.

I have managed to get the image for each company along with the name. I am doing this by using Google Places api however I get a null exception when trying to call “formated_phone_number”.

How would I go about pulling the specific phone number?

Thanks!

Comment: share the code which you have tried so far...

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/OJeU2

Comment: Thanks btw! This is driving me mad!

Comment: This is the tutorial i have been following partly http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift